# Visual Studio Scaling DPI Problems

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

So, I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2019 but now it seems impossible.
I'm running a 3840 x 2160 screen.

I'm trying to add a Background image to my WinForm with 583 x 452 but the image zooms and gets blurry.

I've tried changing the scale of my display, disabling DPI etc but nothing works.

Any idea or advice please?

Comment: WinForms?  WPF?  etc/

Comment: Sorry, WinForms.

Comment: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103) -- [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms)

Comment: @Jimi That works perfectly on Run-Time, but I'm experiencing the same issue on Designer mode. Any suggestion? And thanks a lot =)

Comment: I run Windows 10 at 150% zoom. When I start VS 2017 and open the forms designer it offers to restart Visual Studio in 100% mode. Not saying this will fix your issue but maybe it will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/disable-dpi-awareness?view=vs-2019

Comment: When in the VisualStudio's Designer, DpiAwareness doesn't apply. As suggested in a previous comment and by VisualStudio itself, design at 100% (usually 96/120 dpi).